# Regex Findall Hang in Linux

Tags: python, regex, linux

I make a program to find a float inside string using re.findall, as follows:

```
string1 = 'Voltage = 3.0 - 4.0 V'
string2 = '3.66666'

float1 = re.findall('\d+.\d+', string1)
float2 = re.findall('\d+.\d+', string2)
```

This program runs well on windows, but when I tried to run the program on Linux, the program keep being stuck on the second re.findall. Any idea what cause this problem? How to solve this?

Thank you

Comment: Can you show us the actual strings used?

Comment: string1 = Voltage = 3.0 - 4.0 V
string2 = 3.6666

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your regex as raw string and also you need to escape the dot. Dot is a special meta character in regex which matches any character except line breaks. Escaping the dot in your regex will match a literal dot.

```
float1 = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+', string1)
float2 = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+', string2)
```

[From `re` doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

> Regular expressions use the backslash character ('\') to indicate special forms or to allow special characters to be used without invoking their special meaning. This collides with Python’s usage of the same character for the same purpose in string literals; for example, to match a literal backslash, one might have to write '\\' as the pattern string, because the regular expression must be \, and each backslash must be expressed as \ inside a regular Python string literal.
>
> The solution is to use Python’s raw string notation for regular expression patterns; backslashes are not handled in any special way in a string literal prefixed with 'r'. So r"\n" is a two-character string containing '\' and 'n', while "\n" is a one-character string containing a newline. Usually patterns will be expressed in Python code using this raw string notation.

```
>>> string1 = 'Voltage = 3.0 - 4.0 V'
>>> string2 = '3.66666'
>>> float1 = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+', string1)
>>> float2 = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+', string2)
>>> float1
['3.0', '4.0']
>>> float2
['3.66666']
```

Comment: still no luck, it is still stuck on the second expression. I wonder why this kind of problem doesn't happen on windows

Comment: could you provide the contents of string1 and string2?

Comment: string1 = Voltage = 3.0 - 4.0 V,
string2 = 3.6666

Comment: @ferryard works for me. What's the output you got after running the second command?